# Trying to build a VS2010 csproj from command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, target

The error I get is:

> c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\microsoft.csharp.targets(132,9) : error MSB4066: The attribute "Returns" in element  is unrecognized.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What command are you running?

Answer (score 4):

The `Returns` attribute is new for MSBuild 4. Is your project targeting an older version of the .NET Framework?

If it isn't, I suggest you try changing the project to target .NET Framework 4 and see if it solves the problem.

If this doesn't help, run the command `msbuild /version` to check which version you are running. If it's not version 4.0.30319.1, you are running an old version that doesn't know what `Returns` means. If that's the case, you probably also have Visual Studio 2008 installed, and maybe it has precedence over Visual Studio 2010 in your `PATH` environment variable.